# SPFX Webpart- "Error initializing application" after refreshing page

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions

SPFX app is created and deployed tenant level. IF it is add to a page at site collection level (ex:https://text.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC) it is working perfectly. If it is added at subsite level (ex:https://text.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/AA) first time it is working properly and if we reload the page then getting  "Error initializing application" error.

Error Message:

> Can't load the application on this page. Use the browser Back button to retry. If the problem persists, contact the administrator of the site and give them the information in Technical Details.
>   TECHNICAL DETAILS
>   Error details: Error: ***Error initializing application.

TECHNICAL DETAILS
Error details: Error: ***Error initializing application. Error: Error: ***Error initializing application. Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Content' of undefined

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue and the only way it was fixed was when I changed the setting "IsDomainIsolated" to false. 
when I created my spfx solution using gulp it created the file "package-solution.json" and I left this settings as created

{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/package-solution.schema.json",
  "solution": {
    "name": "webpartName",
    "id": "d3529353-4123-4e20-94df-1231231231",
    "version": "1.0.0.0",
    "includeClientSideAssets": true,
    "skipFeatureDeployment": true,
    "isDomainIsolated": **false**,

},
  "paths": {
    "zippedPackage": "solution/xxxx.sppkg"
  }
}

It field IsdomainIsolated was set to true and I was having the same errors when I set it to false, create the package and deploy it worked fine.

Hope It helps